# command to email file as an attachment

Tags: email-attachments

I'm using the following command to send an email with a specific file attached from the web server to me

```
mail -A /home/root/BACKUPS/backup.sql -s "$(date +%F) sql Backup" me@domain.com < /dev/null
```

**Resource:** https://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/

Problem is that although it is sending me an email, it's not attaching the item (backup.sql).

Does anyone see the problem with this code? Or is there something else that needs to be done to make the code work?

Comment: If running as sudo works OK, it's a permissions issue with acessing root's files.

Comment: Should `-a` be lowercase?

Comment: I got the same results with -a and -A. As for the permissions I already have two other working lines governing the files in that directory, so the permissions are good. both the directory and the file being emailed are set to allow this. And it is sending the email but without the attachment.